# Extend the Voter Fraud Script to invalidate excessive cross-voting

Tags: feature-request, sock-puppets, serial-voting

The Voter Fraud script that runs overnight automatically removes votes from users who serially downvote another specific user.  My idea is a simple one: extend this functionality to cross-voters.

We already have mechanisms to research sock puppets.  But doing so is a complex, time-consuming and subjective process having many moving parts, often requiring a cauldron and extract of unicorn horns.

What I propose is much simpler and completely objective: Invalidate cross-votes between users that rise above some secret threshold, and are seen at the same group of IP addresses.

Example, for illustrative purposes only:

User A has 1500 rep, with 50% of their votes coming from User B having 25 rep, who casts 80% of their votes against User A.  User A and B are always at the same IP address(es). User B is a clear sock.  Votes are invalidated during the next nightly voter fraud script run.

The advantages of this approach are:

1. The rules are applied equally to everyone
2. The rules don't care who the participants are; the script will work whether it is a sock or a coworker.

Comment: Does this just invite the cheaters to generate a larger clique with which to run their scam?

Comment: @dmckee: Perhaps. But it adds more friction; the user has to create more socks, and the threshold could be lowered for accounts coming from the same group of IP's.

Comment: Adding more friction is the key.

Comment: *throws a pile of socks at Robert* - You'll never find me now!

Comment: Related, I think: Robert's [Limit the maximum percentage of upvotes an account can cast against a single user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116882/limit-the-maximum-percentage-of-upvotes-an-account-can-cast-against-a-single-use) which however did not propose *a secret* limit.

Comment: @animuson so _that's_ where my missing socks went :p

Comment: *This sounds familiar... I likes.*