# How to Handle Revenge Votes?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, review, down-votes

I'm a regular reviewer of Stack Overflow.
Usually when I down vote any question or answer, I put comments. So that the OP can improve.
But recently when I put comment, Within seconds I get one or two down votes for any of my questions.

Usually these down votes won't come under serial down voting, because I'm getting 1 or 2 down votes.

How to handle this situation ? Is the only solution is not to put comments when I down vote ? But I don't like that, because when I get anonymous down votes without reason, I'll get irritated. I know if I do anonymous down vote another person also feel like me, that's why I'm putting comment.

I think the pattern of down vote is like this:

1. I down vote and put comment
2. OP will select my name and check my profile
3. OP will choose any one or two questions from my profile
4. Down vote it

Is there a way to identify and block this pattern of downvotes?

Comment: My solution is to stop explaining your downvotes. Not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147374/a-better-serial-voting-trap

Comment: Or do not comment & downvote at the same time.  Comment first, then if the issue is not addressed, then downvote.  Again, not perfect, but does limit the "revenge" factor.

Comment: These downvotes don't follow the usual revenge pattern.  Not enough of them and too much time between votes.  You simply inspired somebody to review your posts in turn and treat them the same way you did.  Minus the comment, that's entirely optional.  For obvious reasons.